# Dynamically updating table layout in android app

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am building an app for android that dynamically updates a table layout with table rows. The way I do this, is by having a fixed table row layout that I populate with content and then insert it to the table layout and it displays like seen below.

[image: TableLayout1]

The problem I'm having is that when I add a row that contains content that is longer in the middle part and creates multiple lines on one of the text views, it somehow shortens the width of the layout that contains the two text views of the other rows (middle part), specifically those that have single lines, for example the first and second row in the image below.

[image: TableLayout2]

You can find the code below. If you need any more code or examples, please tell me.

row_main.xml - The fixed layout of the row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableRowMain1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewEmployeeName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewClientId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTimeStamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOrder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewOrder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewOrderDetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonDelete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="@string/cross" 
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</merge>
```

MainActivity.xml (snippet) - Where the table row is inserted.

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:overScrollMode="always" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayoutMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I really can't figure out how to solve this or what may be causing it... Please help!

Thank you in advance! :)

Note: The pink/red rectangles is the "Show layout bonds" tool from the developer options in android.

EDIT: I replaced the TableLayout with a Vertical LinearLayout and it works just fine. I guess I was overcomplicating it... :P

Comment: Any special reason why you are not using RecyclerView/ListView?

Comment: Not really... A table just seemed like a good option... You think switching to RecyclerView/ListView would solve this problem?